# Configuring libmediainfo to work with Java project without installation across all platforms (OSes)

Tags: java, linux, macos, jna, mediainfo

I am using mediainfo (http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to extract information from audio and video files using Java code.

My java project runs over all platforms (osx, win & linux). So far I have only tested mediainfo over osx where the procedure is simple: just put libmediainfo.dylib in the target folder and access it using a native library and you're good to go. And the solution works flawlessly...

I am now looking to expand this functionality to the other OSs, starting with Linux. However, it is proving to be more of a challenge than I thought.
At first I kept getting this:

```
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mediainfo': libmediainfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

and this was expected as it was looking in /usr/lib

but this was solved by installing the suitable libmediainfo0 & libzen0 ".deb from http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download/Ubuntu

Still, my solution needs to be portable, meaning, I want all necessary resources to be included with the java project package without requiring any further installations.
I also need to know if it's possible to change mediainfo to look for the resources in my java package instead of a system location.

For your reference, I am using Java Native Access (jna) to interact with the library. Also using the MediaInfo.java & MediaInfoLibrary.java classes that the website suggests.
Let me know if you need other details.

any wisdom is highly appreciated
thanks!!

Comment: The latest release of JNA (3.5.2) will automatically unpack native libraries [bundled as resources](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html) (whether file- or jar-based).

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: If you include you shared library for linux/amd64 as /linux-x86-64/libmylibrary.so in one of your jar files, JNA will extract it and load it automatically when you call `Native.loadLibrary("my library")`.  Older versions of JNA require that you make the library available on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (envariable) or `jna.library.path` (system property).

Comment: that's it! it finally worked (@ least on linux for now)
i added the resources in the jar file under "linux-i386" dir
sweeeeet!!
could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it
thx a million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest release of JNA (3.5.2) will automatically unpack native libraries [bundled as resources](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html) (whether file- or jar-based).

If you include you shared library for linux/amd64 as `/linux-x86-64/libmylibrary.so` in one of your jar files, JNA will extract it and load it automatically when you call `Native.loadLibrary("my library")`. Older versions of JNA require that you make the library available on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (envariable) or `jna.library.path` (system property).

Comment: just as an extra, for ubuntu 12.04 i386 the resources (libmediainfo.so & libzen.so) had to be placed in a dir named linux-i386. 

How can i tell what names should other folders have on other platforms??

Comment: `Native.getNativeLibraryResourcePrefix()` (which will be an alias to `Platform.RESOURCE_PREFIX` in subsequent releases).